# Dojo modeless alert display

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to display an alert box using Dojo. The alert box behavior will be modeless. All work is done through a Javascript which has functions to addScript/CSS and these functions work fine. Though i am not bale to display alert using Dojo. Here is my code:

//DojoThemes and Libraries

```
addStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css');
    addStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css');
    addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.js');

    //dojo.require("dojo.ready");
    //dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");


    var dojoDialogBox = document.createElement('script');
    dojoDialogBox.innerHTML = 'require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/Dialog"], function(ready, Dialog){ ready(function(){ myDialog = new Dialog({ title: "My Dialog", content: "Test content.", style: "width: 300px" }); }); });';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(dojoDialogBox);



    function myFuncc() {
        myDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  addStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css');
  addStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css');
  addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.js');
</script>
<!--
     closing script tag here will allow dojo.js script 
     tag to get written - otherwise
     'require' is an undefined
-->
<script>
  require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
    myDialog = new Dialog({
         title: "My Dialog",

         // since we are inside a require(function() {}) closure, lets set an ID
         // so that externally (from outside this require function) we can get the dialog

         id:'myDialog',
         content: "Test content.",
         style: "width: 300px"
    });
  });
  function myFuncc() {
      dijit.byId('myDialog').show();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?